# mb_detect_encoding ever is ASCII

Tags: php, html, utf-8, ascii

```
$output = "ALLWILLBEASCII";
foreach ($output as $name => $value) {
    echo mb_detect_encoding( $value );
}
```

How to convert from ASCII to UTF-8 in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

if a character is valid ASCII, it is valid UTF-8 there is nothing to convert. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: Then why it is not possible to combine UTF-8 and ASCII strings in `json_encode` if it is all the same?

Answer (score 2):

The characters of ASCII are a subset of Unicode and the code words of ASCII are also valid UTF-8. So you need no conversion as every ASCII string is also a valid UTF-8 string (but not vice versa).

Comment: @Green What makes you think so?

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems I just forgot to `JSON.parse` the response from the server. I use russian language for the answers about validation of user's credentials in ZF2. So when I set some russian messages (utf-8 if `mb_detect_encoding`) and some messages are defaults from ZF2 (ASCII if `mb_detect_encoding`), and I combine them in one json answer, I see in `alert(xhr.response)` that russian ones are like `["\u0440\u0436\u0438\u0442...` but english ones are normal `"The input appears to be a DNS hostname...`. But after `JSON.parse(xhr.response)` they all are normal :)

Comment: @Green Some JSON encoder choose to play it safe and encode any non-ASCII characters using a Unicode escape sequence `\uxxxx` (see [RFC 4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2.5)) for compatibility with protocols that are based on plain ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mb_convert_encoding() or iconv() to convert character encoding.